# phpsh installation problems on ubuntu latest version

Tags: ubuntu, phpsh

I've been found an error, when i install phpsh on ubuntu.

```
nadeem@nadeem-Inspiron-5521:~/Downloads/phpsh$ phpsh
Starting php
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/phpsh", line 47, in <module>
    verbose=opts.verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpsh/__init__.py", line 503, in __init__
    self.php_open_and_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpsh/__init__.py", line 641, in php_open_and_check
    self.php_open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpsh/__init__.py", line 698, in php_open
    preexec_fn=os.setsid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
nadeem@nadeem-Inspiron-5521:~/Downloads/phpsh$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing phpsh on linux, Python error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741212/installing-phpsh-on-linux-python-error)

Comment: Can u please have a look that screenshot:
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/731645/2072837bfa6caeb6e708272f59077908